# Probability of at least 1 event occuring versus combined probability of every possible scenario

Tags: probability

So let's say i have 3 events, A,B,C completely independent from one another.
If I calculate the "possibility of at least one event occurring" will that include the probability of 2 events occurring or even all of them?

If we take all possible scenarios:

- A occurs but NOT B, and NOT C
- B Occurs, but NOT A, and NOT C
- C occurs, but NOT A, and NOT B
- A AND B occur, but NOT C
- A AND C occur, but NOT B
- B AND C occur, but NOT A
- A AND B AND C occur

This way we take into consideration of all possibilities where one event occurs but we also include the possibility of more than one events occurring.

So why is the probability using this scenario, lower than the probability of A OR B OR C? am I missing something here? shouldn't the be at least the same if not even more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the Inclusion-Exclusion principle, you get 
\begin{align}
P(A\cup B \cup C) =& P(A) + P(B)+ P(C)\\
 &- P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap C) - P(B\cap C)\\
& + P(A\cap B\cap C), \\
\end{align}
And then using independence in order to compute the joint probabilities.
Alternatively, by using De-Morgan's law and independence you can write
$$
 P(A\cup B \cup C)=1-P(\bar{A}\cap \bar{B} \cap \bar{C})=1-P(\bar{A})P(\bar{B})P(\bar{C}).
$$
Finally, you can add up all the probabilities for all possible (mutually) disjoint events - as you did. 
All the "methods" should yield the same result.